# TimeSpan utc0 to timezone and some days

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

Hi i have some table with starttime end time and timezone

I get data in DateTime.Utc

http://prntscr.com/a84tr3

And how i can check if the date what comes is get caught in this timezome from DB and this day

0-Monday... 5-Friday

If we have 0-1 this means start time in 23:00 Sunday to 22:00 Monday

```
public static DateTime GetDateTimeWithExchangeTimeZoneSessionStart(DateTime tickDateTime, string exchangeTimeZone)
    {
        DateTime convertedDateTime = tickDateTime;
        switch (exchangeTimeZone)
        {
            case "5.5":
                convertedDateTime = convertedDateTime.AddHours(-5.5);
                break;
            case "4":
                convertedDateTime = convertedDateTime.AddHours(-4);
                break;
            case "-6":
                convertedDateTime = convertedDateTime.AddHours(6).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            case "0":
                break;

        }
        return convertedDateTime;
    }
```

But it's not good i think

Comment: Are you sure about your -6 value? That seems unlikely to be right.

Comment: yes it's NY time zone

Comment: Well you've subtracted 18 hours, effectively. That's *not* New York.

Comment: it is Chicago time but it's not mater how i can check it with days

Comment: You've missed my point - adding 6 hours and then subtracting a whole day is equivalent to subtracting 18 hours. There is no timezone that that is appropriate for.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's important to understand that what you've got isn't a time zone. It's a UTC offset (although the negation of what it would normally be...). A real time zone would need to indicate how that UTC offset varies over time (e.g. due to daylight saving time changes).

However, with the data you've got, it looks like all you need is:

```
double hours = double.Parse(exchangeTimeZone, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
return tickDateTime - offset;
```

However:

- It would be cleaner to use `DateTimeOffset` given that you really *do* have a `DateTime` and an offset
- Be *really, really careful* around `DateTime.Kind`... basically, [`DateTime` is somewhat broken](http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).
- (Shameless plug) Consider using my [Noda Time project](http://nodatime.org) to make your code much clearer for this and all your other date/time code

Answer (score 0):

i need check if the date what come - is in this days from DB
How it's will be code with dateofday method and this data 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

maybe write some class with this sessionstart sessionend and settlementime fields - and check this in utc0 and this time 17:00 etc.